# Apple LLVM 5.1 Error in .pch file

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been working on a project and when i copy paste files to folder it gave the following error,

```
ProcessPCH /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/QuizUsingDB-Prefix-djuulhnvjwmesvgsapmhptggwtmh/QuizUsingDB-Prefix.pch.pch QuizUsingDB/QuizUsingDB-Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd "/Users/ankit/Desktop/iOS Examples/QuizUsingDB"
export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -iquote /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Intermediates/QuizUsingDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QuizUsingDB.build/QuizUsingDB-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Intermediates/QuizUsingDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QuizUsingDB.build/QuizUsingDB-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Intermediates/QuizUsingDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QuizUsingDB.build/QuizUsingDB-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Intermediates/QuizUsingDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QuizUsingDB.build/QuizUsingDB-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Intermediates/QuizUsingDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QuizUsingDB.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Intermediates/QuizUsingDB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QuizUsingDB.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator --serialize-diagnostics /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/QuizUsingDB-Prefix-djuulhnvjwmesvgsapmhptggwtmh/QuizUsingDB-Prefix.pch.dia -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/QuizUsingDB-Prefix-djuulhnvjwmesvgsapmhptggwtmh/QuizUsingDB-Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/ankit/Desktop/iOS\ Examples/QuizUsingDB/QuizUsingDB/QuizUsingDB-Prefix.pch -o /Users/ankit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuizUsingDB-bijvpcomctoytfblslktqvqbwaom/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/QuizUsingDB-Prefix-djuulhnvjwmesvgsapmhptggwtmh/QuizUsingDB-Prefix.pch.pch
```

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/ankit/Desktop/iOS Examples/QuizUsingDB/QuizUsingDB/QuizUsingDB-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: The prefix file is missing...

Comment: Not according to `clang` it isn't.  Go to the command line and confirm it's at the location specified.

Comment: can you elaborate how to do that??

Comment: Start `Terminal.app` and type `cd '/Users/ankit/Desktop/iOS Examples/QuizUsingDB/QuizUsingDB` then `ls QuizUsingDB-Prefix.pch` and see what it says.  Or use `Finder`.

Comment: check path of .pch file in Build Settings->Prefix Header

Comment: same issue here, just copied a project from one device to an other, and got the same problem. It clearly runs on the first one, and the settings and versions are the same.